# ScrollView rounded corners dissappear when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with a background drawable xml with rounded corners:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" 
  >

<solid
    android:color="@color/target" >
</solid>
<stroke
    android:width="0dp">
</stroke>


<corners
    android:radius="8dp"   >
</corners>
```

The problem appears when user scrolls, the view inside the scrollView hide the rounded corners, how to avoid this? (need scrolling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the scrollview in a linearlayout and set the background drawable to the linear layout.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone got this probleme is solved it by : 
Creating an xml file : **corner_radius.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

The solide color is for the inside of you layout and the stroke color is if you want to add a border. then you have the classic corner radius to set up the angle of your corner and the padding that you want.

Then you add : `android:background="@drawable/corner_radius"` to you scrollView in your xml layout and you are good to go